# Issue with reading csv file in R software with year variable

Tags: r

I am reading some csv files for each year and every table has a year (two digit year), day and month column; instead I need one column just with the date. I was doing fine using my R code until for one of the tables the year variable has four digits (e.g. 2000). In this case my code convert this year to 2020.

Any thoughts?

```
dt_00$date=as.Date(with(dt_00,paste(MONTH,DAY,YEAR,sep='-')),'%m-%d-%y)
```

Comment: I edited your post to fix the language and formatting issues. Why did you revert back? Please use proper language and code formatting.

Comment: It's not clear what was before, what changed and how it broke your code. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Before 2000 ,year was two digit and i used the code i proveded,it did not worked for year 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Because lubridate accommodates quite a few date format varieties, this might work:

```
library(lubridate)
dt_00$date <- mdy(dt_00$date)
```

Comment: When the issue is dates and times in R,`lubridate` is often the first tool I grab from the toolbox.

Comment: @Freniks, I think if you add some sample representative data to your question we'll be able to help more easily.

Comment: @dbo,Can we chat ?